# using ply.lex on a stringified list of json objects

Tags: python-2.7, ply

i have a stringified python list of json objects, which i have  partially lexed.

but i am left with tokens such as "u'Grimsby'" or "u'Amsterdam'" and i am struggling to get rid of the preceding u without damaging word tokens that are actually supposed to start with "u".

so i was hoping somebody could help me write a

```
 t_ignore
```

or a

```
def t_u(token):
```

that will safely get rid of these "u"s

thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason why you are not using the [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) function to parse the json string, and have chose instead to build your own parser?

Answer (score 1):

You won't always be able to safely convert unicode into a string if there are non-ascii characters, for example `str(u'ü')` will raise:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0:
>    ordinal not in range(128)

but you can lex it as follows and keep the `u`:

```
def t_unicode(token):
    r'u\'[^\']*\'|u\"[^"]*\"'
```

*Note: when you `print u'ü'` it only displays `ü` (so the u isn't a problem).*

.

Depending on the context, if you really wanted, you could ignore the `u` *(but since it'll still be a unicode string this seems a bit pointless)*:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

def t_u(token):
    r'u'
```

And then in your ply ignore the `u` (assuming `string` is already defined):

```
def p_unicode_string(p):
    'expression : u string'
    p[0] = p[2]
```